# When writing to Firestore, changes to the code are not reflected in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I create a program that writes to the Firestore and run it, the program works as expected. However, when I make changes to the program, the changes may not be reflected and the previous program may be written to the Firestore.

before

```
likeList.forEach((uid) {
  doc.reference.collection('like').document(uid).setData(
      {'$uid': true, 'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()},
      merge: true);
});
```

after change like to dislike. but dislike collection wont be created. Only like collection created, though I changed collection name 'like' to 'dislike'.

```
likeList.forEach((uid) {
  doc.reference.collection('dislike').document(uid).setData(
      {'$uid': true, 'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()},
      merge: true);
});
```

If document or subcollection does not exit, setData will create it. However, sometimes it wont work after making changes to code.
How can I solve this?

Comment: add the snippet of the code that you change

Comment: edited code changes!

Comment: try adding a break point to the part where you 'dislike' and try disliking on app and see if the method is called